# Parallel horizontal slide of legs according to angle tilt of cylinder

Tags: rigging, drivers

[image]I got stuck on this challenge to get the legs (armature 001 - 003) slide on the floor when tilting the cylinder as they almost do right in my example. They need to stay parallel to the cylinder. This I have achieved with trial and error but I am shure there is a geometrical(trigonometrical) solution that works with defined formulas!?
The slide is driven by drivers and it does not work with transformation constraint because they have to slide in the same direction at both positive and negative tilting.
The goal is to make this work in various dimensions and clearly reproduceable.
The one leg on the X-Axis is the least problem as it just follows the rotation of the center bone when tilted in in the Y direction (no slide) and works with my solution on straight X.
Only up till a certain angle (max 30°-40°) of course because at heavy tilt the rig (also in nature) does not allow the idea.
The rig is set up with bones damped track constrained to the empties.
The biggest problem shows up when tilted somewhere between X and Y direction (at least armature 002 and 003).
I have no idea on trigonomy what so ever! Maybe someone could clear up ;o)
Help is highly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.